# Open saved POST requests in a browser using Postman?

Tags: postman

I'm trying to troubleshoot a site that uses dozens of form POST variables.  Using Postman Interceptor, I'm able to capture the requests, but I would really like to open/replay them in the browser.  Is that possible?

Yes, I know this is bad design, and yes I know that these POSTS should be idempotent or I'm going to get weird results. But that's the nature of the site I'm working on.

I know Postman is designed for RESTful API testing (which is great) but can I use it to simply capture and replay actual HTTP POSTs in the browser?  Is there a better tool I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the postman request from your browser directly you may try to use [Postman Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) or [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en).

On the other hand, you may try to copy your Postman request in JS - XHR Style from [Code snippet](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/) and execute generated code from your browser console.